# Create a template for classes

Tags: class, factory, mobx

I have 10+ classes (MobX stores, but not relevant) which have 90% of code in common:

PriceStore.js

```
// Store to get the latest price of something
class PriceStore {
  @observable price;
  @observable error;

  constructor() {
    someSocket.on('price', this.setPrice);
    someSocket.on('price_error', this.setError)
  }

  static instance = null; // To enforce a singleton

  static get() {
    if (!PriceStore.instance) {
      PriceStore.instance = new PriceStore();
    }
    return PriceStore.instance;
  }

  @action setPrice = price => this.price = price;

  @action setError = error => this.error = error;
}
```

LatestUserStore.js

```
// Store to get the latest signed up user
class LatestUserStore {
  @observable latestUser;
  @observable error;

  constructor() {
    someSocket.on('latestUser', this.setLatestUser);
    someSocket.on('latestUser_error', this.setError)
  }

  static instance = null; // To enforce a singleton

  static get() {
    if (!LatestUserStore.instance) {
      LatestUserStore.instance = new LatestUserStore();
    }
    return LatestUserStore.instance;
  }

  @action setLatestUser = latestUser => this.latestUser = latestUser;

  @action setError = error => this.error = error;

  @computed get fullname() { ... }; // This store has an additional method.
}
```

My problem is: how can I factorize this 90% of code?

Ideally, I would like to write myself a createMobxStore function, so that I could use it the following way:

```
const PriceStore = createMobxStore('price');
// Now I'll be able to use PriceStore as if it was defined like above.

const BaseLatestUserStore = createMobxStore('latestUser');
class LatestUserStore extends BaseLatestUserStore {
  @computed get fullname() { ... };
}
// Now I'll be able to use LatestUserStore as if it was defined like above.
```

I would like some help to write this createMobxStore function, if possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to create that class dynamically.

I created a wrapper function that should (not tested) create that store class, with dynamic observable and setter function using the `storeName` parameter.

```
function createStore(storeName) {

    return class Dynamic {
        @observable error;

        constructor() {
            // this[storeName];
            extendObservable(this, {
                [storeName]: null,
                ['set' + storeName]: action((value) => this[storeName] = value)
            })

            someSocket.on(storeName, this['set' + storeName]);
            someSocket.on('price_error', this.setError)
        }

        static instance = null; // To enforce a singleton

        static get() {
            if (!Dynamic.instance) {
                Dynamic.instance = new PriceStore();
            }
            return Dynamic.instance;
        }

        @action setError = error => this.error = error;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
const UserStore = createStore('user');

class SomeStore extends UserStore {

    moreActions() { ... }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Exactly. I finally went for plain JS objects instead of classes, I still find es6 classes confusing.